# Different output on different machine python code

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import multiple csv files into a dictionary. My idea is key is present the name of csv files, and value of each key is the table inside csv as DataFrame type.

My code is like this :

```
import pandas as pd

data = '.././data/raw/'
all_files = [data + 'x.csv', data + 'y.csv']
list_a = []
result_dict = dict()
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, encoding='mac_roman')
    key = filename.split('/')[1]
    result_dict[key]=df

# print(result_dict)


def get_dataframe(name):
    dataframe = result_dict.get(name)
    return dataframe

m_taiin =get_dataframe('x.csv')
type(m_taiin)
print(isinstance(m_taiin,pd.DataFrame))
```

But when I run this code on my Macbook - Python3.7 and my Ubuntu 16.04 - Python3.6 has result True.

But when I run on Arch Linux - Python 3.7 my result is False. The value is NoneType not DataFrame.

I don't know which is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in for loop ...

```
key = filename.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is my mistake caused by different path on different machine.
[-1] should be fine to get the name.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid cross-platform issues with `split`, I suggest you split on `os.sep` which is the OS-dependent file separator.

Also, I would suggest you use the `glob` library for listing `.csv` files in a folder and dictionary comprehension to create your dict.

That said, you can achieve your goal, i.e. having a dictionary where the keys are the filenames and the values are the actual dataframes like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

data = '.././data/raw/'    
all_files = glob.glob(data+'*.csv')
result_dict = {csv_file.split(os.sep)[-1]: pd.read_csv(csv_file) for file in all_files}
```

Of course pay attention to having only the wanted `.csv` in the data folder and not others because `glob.glob` will list all the `.csv`.